# How do I set the name of a Stage Instance name of a Movie Clip with JSFL

Tags: flash, jsfl

When I create a movie clip with JSFL and I set the .name parameter - this becomes the name of the Movie Clip as it appears in the library - I want to supply an instance name for the movie clip on the stage however. I've attached a pic to show the field that I'm attempting to populate via JSFL.

Thanks!

[image]

Here's the code that sets the name, basically looping through the fl.getDocumentDOM() until I get an array of all elements on stage then once I have an element.

```
var newMc = fl.getDocumentDOM().convertToSymbol("movie clip", mcName, "top left");
newMc.name = "row_" + rowq.toString() + "_column_"+ colq.toString();
newMc.linkageExportForAS=true;      
newMc.linkageClassName="com.xyz.as3.view.component.Piece";
```

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newMC` is the library item rather than the stage instance, but the new instance should be selected now, so you could use:

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().selection[0].name
```